# Why does static charge build up and how do I prevent it?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I bought my 11-month-old son a tricycle from Smart Trike ([official website](https://smartrike.com)) and I have noticed that after a few laps indoors on my marble floors static charge would build up in him as I can see his hair standing up, and when I touch him I get zapped. This does not happen when we play the tricycle outdoors on pavement. We live in a Southeast Asian tropical country with high humidity. How do I prevent static charge from building up? Thank you.

As a side note I contacted Smart Trike and the reply they gave to me was just a long copy-and-paste from Google on "How to remove static electricity."

[image]

Comment: A strap from the Trike to the floor, like the ones you see on the back of cars, to stop people getting a shock when they slide on the plastic seats and then ground themselves.

Comment: @count_to_10 thanks for your comment. A strap made of what do you suggest? and where should it be attached to?

Comment: Buy a humidifier?

Comment: You can just connect a wire to the handle (something metallic) and leave it to touch the ground so that as soon as charge builds up on the trycycle, they are transfered back to the ground. This system basically throws away the charges before they reach your son. The charge buildup is due to the friction between the floor and the wheels. If they have to reach your son, they have to travell through somewhere possibly metals. So the wire being a good conductor transfers any excess charge that builds up on the metal handle. You just need to ensure that the other end of the wire touchs the floor.